# La traducción de "We like it when we (verbo)": ¿Con subjuntivo o indicativo?

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo, conjugación

Estaba pensando en la frase inglesa

> We like it when we see them clean

("them" se refiere a unas baldosas previamente mencionadas)

Llego a

> Nos gusta cuando las veamos limpias

porque, a mi entender, no es una declaración y por eso exige subjuntivo (o se puede decir que "gustar" es un verbo de "emoción").

Sin embargo no estoy seguro de que el indicativo sea correcto aquí.

Puede que la traducción más correcta sea

> Nos gusta verlas limpias

pero para mí falta un poco del matiz del original.

¿Que sería lo correcto? ¡Agradeceré cualquier consejo!

Comment: Yo no veo la diferencia de matiz; otra cosa sería que la frase original fuera "We like **them** when we see them clean" que induce a pensar que, cuando no las ven limpias, no les gustan. Yo escogería "Nos gusta verlas limpias" (lo que gusta no son las baldosas, es el ver que están limpias).

Answer (score 3):

*"porque, a mi entender, no es una declaración"*

Mmm... Quizá es por no hablar inglés nativo, pero yo sí que lo veo como una declaración:

> We like it when we see them clean.

Estás declarando un hecho cierto y objetivo: cuando las veis limpias, os gusta.

Esto es independiente de que el propio gusto sea subjetivo: puede que a otras personas les gusten sucias, o verdes, pero en cada caso es una realidad que eso les gusta.
Por tanto, aplica el indicativo:

> Nos gusta cuando las vemos limpias.

---

Otra cosa distinta es que estés hablando de una posibilidad futura:

> We'll like it when we see them clean.

En este caso estás describiendo una situación hipotética: ahora mismo no os gustan, pero os gustarán *si se dan ciertas condiciones*. Por tanto aplica el subjuntivo:

> Nos gustará cuando las veamos limpias.

---

Por poner un ejemplo quizá más claro:

> I clap when the plane lands → Aplaudo cuando el avión aterri**za**
>   *[I'm just that kind of person.]*

vs

> I'll clap when the plane lands → Aplaudiré cuando el avión aterri**ce**
>   *[I'm telling what I'll do when the plane lands, **if** it lands.]*

Comment: Indicative seems clearly the way to go here. I think it is possible to construct a context which would lead to the subjunctive as for instance: parent to child, threateningly "We like it when we seem them clean". The implication being that they currently are not clean and the child is to clean them. It is a somewhat contrived example though.

Comment: Gracias a todos!  Me he fijado en la de @aparente001 -- debí haber dicho "que" en vez de "cuando".  Mi confusión era sobre la exigencia de usar el subjuntivo cuando se expresa "emoción" o "agradecimiento" -- es decir una "no declaración", como dice Campillo.  Por ejemplo, _no me gusta que vengas_.  Aún así, me parece que este relación _emoción_ --> _subjuntivo_ solo se encuentra con  _que_, no con _cuando_.  Con _cuando_, estamos hablando (a mi entender) sobre una acción repetida (indicativo) o una acción en el futuro (subjuntivo).

Comment: Una cosa más: por cierto, en el _post_ original usé "mentadas" en vez de "mencionadas" (fue corregido por los moderadores).  ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre las dos?  Mi diccionario dice "mention" para ambos.

Comment: @Cerulean - interesante.  Yo no conocía la acepción de *mentar = mencionar*.  Yo solo conocía la grosería que se usa en México: http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/mentar%20la%20madre

Answer (score 2):

Ante estas traducciones idiomáticas/ideológicas yo siempre he preferido que la traducción se mantenga fiel al significado que se quiere transmitir.

En este tipo de casos trato de ver si las traducciones terminan siendo traducibles de vuelta al ingles y si el significado de la frase regresada al ingles no es el mismo entonces termina por no ser de mi agrado.

Por ejemplo

> Nos gusta verlas limpias

Se puede traducir a :

> We like to see them clean

Creo que la frase pierde el énfasis interpretativo original,

**Mi voto es:**

Si se puede mantener una traducción fiel al original, entonces hay que mantenerla. sobre todo cuando es una frase popular:

Las frases no estan hechas para ser gramaticalmente eficientes, están hechas para denotar y hasta connotar algo.

Comment: ¿La conclusión es que debería ser *Nos gusta cuando las vemos limpias*?  Y querías decir algo acerca de la duda del subjuntivo? (Bravo la ortografía, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

No se puede usar el subjuntivo en tu frase (debe ser "nos gusta cuando las vemos limpias"), por dos razones.

1. El punto de vista es igual entre las dos cláusulas
2. "Cuando" no introduce el subjuntivo.  "Que" sí.  Ejemplos:

   > Me gusta que me digas la verdad.
   >
   > Me gusta cuando me dices la verdad.

Ahora, un variante de tu frase, pero con subjuntivo:

> Nos gusta que las veas limpias al llegar a la casa.

(No funcionaría lo siguiente: *Te gusta que las veas limpias* -- por Razon #1, tendría que ser *Te gusta verlas limpias* o *Te gusta cuando las ves limpias*.)

Comment: Nota: el "cuando" en los ejemplos de @walen es para otra cosa -- son para frases que proyectan al futuro.